# Deploying Java/J2EE application at Azure

Tags: java, azure

I am looking to deploy a java application (logistics system) to azure and need step by step guidance/flow to do same. Technical details are:

- Database : SQL server 2008 R2
- Technology (used at server side): java/J2EE,jsp,javascript
- Framework: struts 2
- Server:  Jboss6.0 server
- For report: jasper report(iReport)
- Java Version used: 6.0

The problem is that we do not know which eclipse version is compatible with which Azure sdk version. I installed required azure sdk plugins, but they do not seem working here. So someone who have a complete idea to run this application at azure, please share the detailed flow and process.

Comment: As written, this question will likely be closed as off-topic, as it's asking for recommended documentation. Also, it's quite broad.  You haven't mentioned where you're deploying to: Web apps? Cloud Services (web/worker roles)? VM's? This is an important differentiation. That said, there's plenty of getting-started material for Java + Azure - have you visited the Azure site yet and looked at the documentation there? TL;DR please edit your question with more details before it ends up closed.

Comment: @ArchanaLathia Any update?